# Can't update python packages through anaconda navigator anaconda 2019.07

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda 2019.07, the latest release. I went to the navigator, and looked at packages that can be updated. for example it shows that pandas can be updated, but when I check it, it comes up with the window to show what packages will be updated, but it is empty and the apply button is grayed out. I randomly tried a different package, same issue.

I tried going to the anaconda terminal and doing a conda update navigator, and it said there would be packages downgraded, I don't want that.

Comment: Voting to close as Off-Topic because this sounds like a software bug in the latest Anaconda. Please report it on GitHub - there is already [an open issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11013), so add to that.

Answer (score 4):

You should do

```
conda update --all
```

Yes it will downgrade some packages, but that's normal because as things are released there may be compatibility issues